# Using CH Robotics IMU UM7 with ROS

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the [UM7 Orientation sensor](https://www.chrobotics.com/shop/um7-orientation-sensor) with the [USB Expansion board](https://www.pololu.com/product/1308) from Pololu. I am using [um7_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/um7) to use the IMU with ROS. It is getting detected and the port is `/dev/ttyUSB0`. But when I run `rosrun um7 um7_driver`, it gives the following :

```
[ INFO] [1460061766.522068698]: um7_driver ver 0.0.2 connected to serial port.
[ WARN] [1460061766.620629302]: Timed out waiting for packet from device.
[ WARN] [1460061766.719146180]: Timed out waiting for packet from device.
[ WARN] [1460061766.817532799]: Timed out waiting for packet from device.
[ WARN] [1460061766.915818153]: Timed out waiting for packet from device.
[ WARN] [1460061767.014103974]: Timed out waiting for packet from device.
[ERROR] [1460061767.112069178]: Unable to set CREG_COM_SETTINGS.
[ INFO] [1460061767.112128423]: Attempting reconnection after error.
```

Also, when I run it using **CHR Serial Interface** software in Windows, I get the following error:

```
Error: Timeout while communicating with sensor.
```

In both Ubuntu and Windows, it is getting detected but the Communication is not taking place.
I am not able to find why is this happening. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231380/using-ch-robotics-imu-um7-with-ros/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2016-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-08**:
If the Windows tool also doesn't work, it could be that something is wrong with your hardware. Can you test a minimal scenario? Has it ever worked?

**Comment by [rob_tun](https://answers.ros.org/users/27835/rob_tun/) on 2016-08-25**:
I have the same problem while executing ros but when I tested the um7 with CH Robotics Serial Interface it works fine! However when try to read configuration by CH interfce it is blocked and only create graph works properly
--> communication with um7 is damaged (UM7 is partially damaged I think)

**Comment by [zzzZuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25453/zzzzuo/) on 2017-03-30**:
@Naman @rob_tun, Hi, Naman and rob_tun, now I have the same problem while executing ros node. And my hardware interface is Serial2USB.could you tell me what do you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into this problem last summer. The USB expansion board is crap. Try replacing it.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0